# For which $n$ is $A_n × C_2$ isomorphic to $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Only looking at $n>2$, obviously they have the same number of elements. But if $C_2={e,g}$ then $|{A_n, g}|=|{A_n}|=$|{elements in $S_n$ with even order}| but ${A_n}$ obviously adds more elements with even order so these two groups are never equal when $n>2$.

Does this type of argument work for this exercise? If so, what are other ways to go around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that the center of $S_n$ is trivial if $n>2$.

Comment: Here is a proof https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_Symmetric_Group_is_Trivial